# What is the class of the Arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays

Arrays are Objects and all the objects come from a class. If I execute the following code:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "Hello";
        System.out.println(str.getClass());
    }
}
```

The output is `class java.lang.String`.

But if I execute the following:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int arr[] = new int[10];
        System.out.println(arr.getClass());
    }
}
```

The output is `class [I`.

My questions are:

1. What is the class of the arrays?
2. Why is it the result?
3. If I would like to use the `instanceof` operator how should I use it? If I execute `System.out.println(arr instanceof Object);`, it works perfectly.

Comment: Check [this out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867131/getclass-method-java-with-array-types). It's a duplicate for your first two questions.

Comment: Take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12806739/is-an-array-a-primitive-type-or-an-object-or-something-else-entirely

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This is all specified in the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html).  Arrays are dynamically created `Object`s which implement `Serializable` and `Cloneable`.

The reason you're seeing that come across is due to that being the way the object is [represented in `Class#getName`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName()).

Because you can use [`instanceof` with reifiable `Object` types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.2), and an array is very much reifiable (i.e. concrete, not generic), you can use `instanceof` with arrays:

```
System.out.println(arr instanceof int[]);    // true
System.out.println(arr instanceof String[]); // false
```

The issue with your `arr instance Object` is that `<X> instanceof Object` isn't useful, since *everything* is an `Object` (except primitives, but using `instanceof` with primitives is a compile-time error).

Comment: Thanks @TJCrowder, that's a really good example to add to this.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the other answer, the type can actually be decoded using the string you got as desscribed in [`JVMS: Chapter 4. The class File Format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.3.2):

```
B   byte    signed byte
C   char    Unicode character code point in the Basic Multilingual Plane, encoded with UTF-16
D   double  double-precision floating-point value
F   float   single-precision floating-point value
I   int     integer
J   long    long integer
L ClassName ;   reference   an instance of class ClassName
S   short   signed short
Z   boolean     true or false
[   reference   one array dimension
```

What you got was `class [I`. So `[` which is an array dimension and `I` which is an integer. An array of integers describes the type.