# Is the class object returned by getClass() method an instance of the class?

Tags: java

I understand how the object returned by the method contains  getClass() metadata of the object it is called on, but is the class object being returned an instance of the class of the object it is called upon? This method can be called on any object in Java, so any instance or array. Does it differ for instances and arrays since arrays are in a way special objects?

Comment: No, the object returned by that method is an instance of `Class` and it is a runtime representation of the actual class, which cannot be passed around in code because Java doesn't have first-class types. The `Class` class is used to access methods dynamically and stuff like that. Look up reflection.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867131/getclass-method-java-with-array-types

Answer (score 0):

let's assume a class `Dog`. if you write `new Dog().getClass()` or just `Dog.class` you'll get an instance of `Class<Dog>`. More in the official docs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/class/classNew.html